# N1QL get data from a bucket using the ID from a document. I can't see my results

Tags: database, couchbase, sql++

I want to get data from another bucket using the ID inside a document

The query I'm trying to execute:

```
SELECT meta().id,`docId`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`data` FROM sales AS ccc 
LET contact = (SELECT meta().id,`docId`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`data` FROM contacts AS bbb USE KEYS [ccc.contactId])
WHERE  status = 'active'   LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Source doc:

```
{
"status": "active",
"data": {
      "billingAddress": null,
      "contactId": "1b529239ea294da687559e1464a8c5a8",
      "count": 1,
      "currency": "USD"
}
}
```

The doc I want to get `"1b529239ea294da687559e1464a8c5a8",`

```
{
"id" : "1b529239ea294da687559e1464a8c5a8"
"status": "active",
 "data" : {
           "name": "SpaceX", "location": {}
     } 
}
```

The query response I'm trying to get:

```
{
"status": "active",
"data": {
      "billingAddress": null,
      "contactId": "1b529239ea294da687559e1464a8c5a8",
      "contact": { "data": { "name": "SpaceX"}  }, // *trying to the contact in a contact var by selecting the name*
      "count": 1,
      "currency": "USD"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have never projected contact

```
SELECT ccc.*, OBJECT_CONCAT(ccc.data,concat) AS data  
FROM sales AS ccc 
LET contact = (SELECT {bbb.data.name} AS data
             FROM contacts AS bbb USE KEYS ccc.contactId)[0]
WHERE  status = 'active'  
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```